# Drop down menu going behind flash video

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a flash video and I have a drop down menu. The menu is landing behind the video and I'm not sure how to stop this from happening.

I have tired `wmode="transparent"` with no luck.

the site is [here](http://a-starpromotions.co.uk/sample/index.php)

```
flash code@
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0','width','283','height','200','id','FLVPlayer','src','FLVPlayer_Progressive','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=img/AStarlogointernet&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','FLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','FLVPlayer_Progressive' ); //end AC code
          </script>
            <noscript>
              <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="283" height="200" id="FLVPlayer">
                <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
                <param name="salign" value="lt" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">   
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=img/AStarlogointernet&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
                <embed src="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=img/AStarlogointernet&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" quality="high" scale="noscale" width="283" height="200" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" wmode="transparent" />                        
            </object>
            </noscript>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not forget   `z-index` for "ul.subnav ", and "`wmode=transparent`" as well should be

```
    ul.topnav li ul.subnav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: this has only fixed the problem in firefox

Answer (score 0):

`ul.topnav li ul.subnav` needs `z-index: 1;`

Comment: @StephenWolfe in what browser[s] are you still seeing the problem?

Comment: yeah follow the link i updated the code, the problems are with IE and crome now

Comment: I do not see, "wmode=transparent"  for the object flash and for Param, as ell <param name="wmode" value ="transparent" />, did you add this ?

Comment: @alexander Corotchi i have updated it now and it deff has the wmode tags, still no luck.

Comment: i have updated the code on the post have a look see if i have done it right. cheers

Comment: @StephenWolfe aHA! the wmode param is not closed `..."transparent">` should be `..."transparent" />`

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi any other ideas mate?